# Is there a way to include a file in html using an asp variable?

Tags: html, asp-classic, include

I want to include a file in html but I want to pass it a variable using asp (i.e.)

```
<% Dim s = "file.html %>
<!-- #include file="<% s %>"-->
```

That doesn't seem to work, is there a way around this to get the above to work?

Answer (score 3):

IIS [server side includes](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/serverSideInclude) do not support variables.

See the [documentation](http://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/archive/2010/12/28/iis-notes-on-server-side-includes-ssi-syntax-kb-203064-revisited.aspx).

---

One workaround would be to read the file (using `FileSystemObject`) into a variable and outputting that directly to the page using `<%=%>`.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
<% if condition Then %>
<!--#include file="File1.htm"-->
<% elseif condition Then %>
<!--#include file="File2.htm"-->
<% end if %>
```

Answer (score 0):

What About This ?

```
<% Server.Execute "" & s & ".html" %>
```